# React Navigation previous screen knows when it is activated

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm trying to figure out a way to call a function in my previous screen if it is revisited.

1. Currently on **Screen 1**
2. Click a Button (Goes to **Screen 2**)
3. Click Back (Goes Back to **Screen 1**)

`this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back())`

4. Function on **Screen 1** is called. I don't need to pass any parameters or anything I just need to know when the screen has been called again. I'd rather not clear the entire state and reset it if I don't have t.

Comment: are you using V1 or V2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use didFocus or willFocus listener, please check:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle